# Unused variable not assigned address in Map file

Tags: c, gcc, linker, compiler-optimization

I have Variable in C file which is not used any where just declared and initialized.
I want that variable to be assigned memory in map file which is currently not happening. I want to do with all variables in particular file.

Comment: If you're not using it, why do you need to assign memory to it?

Answer (score 0):

Your compiler is optimizing the unused variable away.

To prevent this from happening (in GCC) you can apply the [*used* attribute](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Variable-Attributes.html#Variable-Attributes):

```
int unreferenced_global_variable __attribute__((used)) = 42;
```

> `used`
>
> This attribute, attached to a variable with the static storage, means that the variable must be emitted even if it appears that the variable is not referenced.
>
> When applied to a static data member of a C++ class template, the attribute also means that the member is instantiated if the class itself is instantiated.

---

A better solution, in my opinion, is to specify these types of variables in a linker script, and add `extern` definitions of them in a header file. But this really depends on *why* you're doing this, which you haven't told us.

Answer (score 0):

you can declare variable with volatile.

Ex: static volatile uint8 variableSample